# clang-format: brace on new line except for empty blocks

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

I'm trying to setup the following formatting:

```cpp
struct no_member {}; // single line

struct one_member
{
    int a;
};

struct multiple_members
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Sadly, clang-format doesn't seem to be able to conditionally break before braces, it's only always or never, and I get stuck with the following formatting:

```
struct empty
{};
```

which I really don't like. There's the same problem with functions or control blocks. You can't have empty brace on a single line and break before in other cases.

That doesn't seem like a very exotic or unusual formatting, is it doable?

Answer (score 1):

I found something similar which may help you.

```
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Empty
```

So the result is:

```
void emptyfn() {}

void myfn() 
{
    //some code
}
```

But this work only for functions,
there is **NOT** option like this:

```
AllowShortStructsOnASingleLine: Empty
```

Here is my .clang-format file https://pastebin.com/ZHmJxQ7g